# pandas two lists of dict in one variable into one list of dict in one variable

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary

I have two lists of dict in one variable want to combine to one list of dict in one variable, how to do?

```
df30 = df10.merge(df21, on='id', how='inner')
df30 = df30.to_dict('records')
```

The variable of df30 inside have 2 lists.

```html
[
  {
    'id': 2101,
    'percent': -10.213240935732046
  }
]

[
  {
    'id': 2100,
    'percent': -77.0623742454728
  }
]
```

I want to combine them into one list of dict, how do I do that?

```html
[
    {
        'id': 2101,
        'percent': -10.213240935732046
    },
    {
        'id': 2100,
        'percent': -77.0623742454728
    }
]
```

or create two new variables for two lists in df30 and combine the two variables is it possible?

Comment: You can't have two lists in one variable. You could have a list of lists.

Comment: You can also have a dataframe containing lists of dicts in the rows.

Comment: You can use + to concatenate lists.

Comment: Can you post some of sample of code?

Comment: It's odd because `df.to_dict('records')` returns a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

Quite confused here, but:

```
l1 = [{'A':1, 'W':10}]
l2 = [{'B':2, 'Y':20}]

l1 + l2
```

Output:

```
[{'A': 1, 'W': 10}, {'B': 2, 'Y': 20}]
```

Comment: not 2 variable, I only have one variable but inside had 2 lists

Comment: @T_Ner Please include code in your question that generates your input data.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples?answertab=oldest#tab-top